# Can't get the jQuery .getScript to work for calling a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, getscript

From the file file2.js I'm trying to call a function foo() that is defined in file1.js.  In file1.js the function looks like:

```
function foo(){
   alert("Here");       
}
```

In file2.js I try calling this function like this:

```
$.getscript('file1.js', function(){
   foo();
});
```

However, this function is not being called.  Any ideas to what I need to do to fix this?  Thanks for any response.

Comment: is that the entirety of file1.js?

Comment: Is file2.js at the same level as file1.js?

Comment: I have one function defined before foo().  Yes, both files are at the same level.

Comment: is foo inside of said function? (incoming game of 20 questions)

Comment: No, foo is defined outside of the function

Comment: your code should work, provide more context.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in `getScript` (note the case):

```
$.getScript('file1.js', function() {...});
```

Per jQuery getScript docs: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/

Comment: I could kiss you.  Thank you for pointing this out.  Working now.

Comment: Awesome, I'm glad that fixed it for you. There should have been an error thrown in your console. If you're unfamiliar with how to view errors or the console, see here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console. Also remember to accept this answer as solving the issue.